# Adding a higher priority webapp classloader to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

Is there a way to add a webapp-specific classloader to tomcat, so that it can override classes from the target webapp?

I'd like to patch classes of a 3rd party application in a clean way, without modifying the original webapp.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to put those libraries at the container level? If so, just drop them in `CATALINA_BASE/lib`.

Comment: Sadly I have to separate by webapp, else I'll get classloading errors.

Comment: You can set your own `ClassLoader` using the `<Loader>` element within `<Context>`. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html. You'd have to write your own `ClassLoader`, but you can just inherit everything from Tomcat's `WebappClassLoader` and put another `URLClassLoader` or something in between, and make sure to load from that one first.

Comment: That looks very promising, post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your own ClassLoader using the  element within . See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html. You'd have to write your own ClassLoader, but you can just inherit everything from Tomcat's `WebappClassLoader` and put another `URLClassLoader` or something in between, and make sure to load from that one first.